# POSTGIS query to get Country,State,admin_level-3,admin_level-4,admin_level-5,admin_level-6 and latitude/ longitude data

Tags: openstreetmap, gazetteer

1. I imported North America data ( https://download.geofabrik.de/north-america.html) into my PostgreSQL database using **import-full.style** provided by **nominatim** with **osm2pgsql** and got the place and spatial_ref_sys tables . Please note I didn't install Nominatim. But used **import-full.style** of **nominatim** for the data import.
2. I connected to the PostgreSQL database using pgAdmin4 and trying to query the "Place" table to get the below information for the name **King Of Prussia** ( something similar to shown in the below screen short marked with Red color Pen ) . But I couldn't find this full information in any column . Can I get the query to get the below kind of full hierarchical path information for any place ?

   > King Of Prussia, Montgomery County, Pennsylvania, United States

[image]

Comment: Welcome to Geographic Information Systems! Welcome to GIS SE! We're a little different from other sites; this isn't a discussion forum but a Q&A site. Your questions should as much as possible describe not just what you want to do, but precisely what you have tried and where you are stuck trying that. Please check out our short [tour] for more about how the site works

Comment: Thank You @IanTurton . Sorry I mentioned in the above question what I tried . Thank You.

Comment: How are you doing the search? What is not working?

Comment: Thanks for your response @IanTurton . I am using my custom application and so to retrieve the data from the database I am looking for a query . Something similar to "SELECT * FROM place WHERE name="King of prussia"

Comment: I am using pgAdmin4 to query the table

Comment: @IanTurton  What I meant is if I query the table , I am not able to get the full hierarchical path like "King Of Prussia, Montgomery County, Pennsylvania, United States" . Is there any column that contains this full path Or do I have to load any other extra data to get this data . Thank You

Comment: please [edit] your question to add the new information - and please take the [tour] to find out how we work here

Comment: Thank You @IanTurton . sorry for my English ,I think my question was confusing . I updated the question. Thanks again .